# OpenGL background clear color bleeds into transparent texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, transparency

I'm writing a simple 2D framework with OpenGL and C++ and have now run into a problem related to transparent textures and blending. I've reduced my problem to the following.

I have two textures: A floor tile and a fish bone. The latter contains transparent pixels. I set my OpenGL clear color to "transparent green" and enable depth test and blending like this:

```
glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

With two calls to `glDrawElements()` I draw the fish and then the floor. The fish has a higher Z value and should thus be placed in front of the floor tile. [This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYEsR.png).

Obviously, I don't want the green box around the fish like that. I think what happens is that the fish pixels blends with whatever is in the framebuffer's color renderbuffer at the moment of drawing and that happens to be a solid green (due to `glClearColor` and `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`). For each transparent pixel in the fish texture, I would have expected this blending to resolve to transparent (as I've set a transparent clear color) but as you can see that isn't what's happening.

If I draw the floor first, and then the fish, it works [as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50URR.png).

My fragment shader is dead simple:

```
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}
```

Do I really have to manage the drawing order manually (ordered by Z coordinate) or is there a way to fix this issue? Isn't the OpenGL depth buffer system designed to address this issue?

I'm testing my program on the iOS simulator through Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe depth sorting is necessary - as even though the resulting pixel from the blend is transparent, the depth buffer IS written. So anything to be drawn behind (higher depth) these transparent pixels is simply discarded. The depth buffer doesn't take transparency into account, unfortunately.

If you don't have any semi-transparent pixels in your textures you could use alpha testing, which discards a pixel if it is transparent and so it doesn't write the depth buffer. This obviously doesn't work (well) with semi-transparent pixels as they either become fully opaque or are discarded depending on your implementation/settings. You could easily implement it by changing your shader to:

```
varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main(void) {
   vec4 tc = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
   if (tc.a < 0.5) //for example, change to any value suitable
     discard;
   gl_FragColor = tc;
}
```

Other than this there is no way I know of to fix transparency with depth buffering besides sorting.

You can read more details on both transparency sorting and alpha testing here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting

Comment: There are methods to do transparency without sorting (e.g. http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5610/lectures/OrderIndependentTransparency.pdf), but I think they are overkill for the situation described here, so I think your answer is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Had this exact issue and tried all sorts to rectify it with no solid results trying to work with the majority of suggestions that centred around changing the calculations being made. In the end it was fairly simple!

The culprit in my code looked like this:

```
glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Despite the fact it was transparent when it was blending between background and the colour of the subject it would bleed. What fixed it for me was wrapping this code to mask the glClear step. It looked like this:

```
glColorMask(false, false, false, true);
glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
```

This seems to negate the bleed issues by eliminating all but the alpha channel from the clear process.

Answer (score 0):

Z Values are used for culling. A fragment is not drawn if there is already another fragment with a smaller z value or it is outside the view frustum. But all Vertex buffer objects are drawn in order. For 2D you can use any sort "by z" algorithm. Discarding fragments will be problematic if you want add some filters like blur or edge anti-aliasing later on.